# How To Access Other Class Instance Variable Inside A Static Function

Tags: c++, static

```
//ClassA.h
Class ClassA
{
    private:

    UtilityClass utilityCls; // this is the instance that I need to access

    virtual void Read();
    static bool IsValid(char c);

}

//ClassA.cpp
void ClassA::Read()
{
    ....
    string str = "abcdefg"; // sample only
    if(find_if(str.begin(), str.end(), IsValid) == str.end())
    {
        ....
    }
}

inline bool IsValid(char c)
{
    // There are compile errors When I call functions of Utility class here
    // Ex: utilityCls.ProcessData();

    return (isalpha(c)); // sample only
}
```

I really need to access "utilityCls" inside the "IsValid" function. Is there a simple way to do this? Or are there any other way or workaround? Sorry if this is a stupid question. Please help me guys...

Comment: Please post *real* code.  This won't even compile

Answer (score 1):

You've got a static function. How are you going to access member variables? Either make the variable static or the function non-static.

Answer (score 1):

A static member function is related to the *class*, not to any *instance* of that class. It's pretty much like a global function that's been declared a friend of the class (with a kind of odd name that includes the class name tacked on the front).

Bottom line: to access (non-static) data, you need to specify an instance of the class whose data it's going to work with (just like you would with a friend function).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making `IsValid` a global function (which you've accidentally done here) or a member function (which I'm sure was your true intent), make it a [functor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object), and in the functor's constructor pass the instance you want to use.

Like this:

```
class ClassA
{
    private:

    UtilityClass utilityCls; // this is the instance that I need to access

    virtual void Read();

  struct IsValid : public std::unary_function<char, bool>
  {
    IsValid(UtilityClass& utility) : utility_(utility) {};
    bool operator()(char c) const 
    {
      return utility_.ProcessData(c);
    }
  };
};
```

Use it like so:

```
void ClassA::Read()
{
    ....
    string str = "abcdefg"; // sample only
    if(find_if(str.begin(), str.end(), IsValid(utilityCls)) == str.end())
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Static functions of a class are really meta-functions: functions which are of use to the class as a whole, but not to any particular object of the class. Thus they don't have any way to access the members of a particular object, in particular they're missing the implied `this` pointer that most member functions contain.

If you need a static class to have access to an object's members, you must explicitly pass a pointer or reference to the object. Usually it's better to make the function non-static.

P.S. Your definition of IsValid is incorrect, it should be `inline bool ClassA::IsValid(char c)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access an *instance* variable without first creating an instance of the class. Either make IsValid non static or add code to your static method like

Class a;
a.utilityCls.ProcessData();